# Getting value from a function which is a parameter for a function

Tags: javascript

I was wondering whether there is a method that can let me print out value like this?

```
socket.emit('location', "Hostel");

socket.on('resultOfLocation', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);   //This can print out value successfully
});
console.log(msg);  //Result is undefined. How can print out value at here?
```

Comment: See [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1529630). It's the same problem.

Comment: @Oriol I think I get some idea from the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround because `socket.on`'s callback function will be called asynchronously after the rest of the script is run.  Therefore the line with undefined result will be run before any code in the callback.

Comment: even if `socket.on` was a synchronous function, `msg` outside the `function(msg)` is not defined

Comment: @Igor true, but we could define it outside the function and we would not be closer to a solution.

Comment: @Igor Since I cannot `msg` outside the `function(msg)`, so I just get all my task done inside the function. I think that is the only way I use it to update my data.